# google usb drivers aren't compatible with Galaxy grand prime?

Tags: android, bootloader, unlock

I have a Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime, I have been following various tutorials trying to unlock the `bootloader`. My device can be found with `adb` devices, but not `fastboot` devices, and all `fastboot` commands are .

The drivers I've got loaded recognize it in 3 ways,
1. Android Device>Samsung Android ADB Interface,
2. Modems>Samsung Mobile USB Modem,
3. Portable Devices>Galaxy Grand Prime.

When my phone is plugged in as `Fastboot` mode, it is recognized as `Modems>Samsung Mobile USB Modem #3`.

I have android sdk, it's working, but when I follow the tutorial found [here](http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/) Between steps 12 and 13, I get a dialoge box saying
`The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems.`

I've got the google drivers located at `C:\Users\"UserName"\Desktop\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver` Which is where I'm telling device manager to find it.

I might need a different driver? or something.

Also, I know you can root the sm-g530h using odin, would this sort of thing work wit this one (sm-530t) without modifying the bootloader?

Also, I've rooted this phone before using kingo root, and it worked, so long as I didn't power down fully, else it would go into a bootloop. just, fyi

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html

Comment: That didn't work, I followed that tutorial to the end, but it doesn't have instructions for samsungs, I haven't tried editing the .inf though, might do that

Answer (score 0):

You need the Samsung USB driver for Galaxy Grand Prime  [listing of all the drivers for USB Samsung](https://androidmtk.com/download-samsung-usb-drivers)

Comment: That's the one I'm using, I've tried pointing it away to this one and towards the google ones, no change, and I've tried forcing these ones, but they just make it show as a modem...

Comment: okay ah I know than what..when yu first plugged it in what setting did you choose on the device? the wrong setting and you get what you expereinced..the settings are media transfer, etc

Comment: and, you need to choose one?

Comment: yes, as there about four choices..otherwise the USB driver does not know which mode you meant..whether you meant media  transfer, modem, etc.

Comment: The five options it gives me are 1. get your stuff on your device (aka Phone companion) 2. Import photos and videos 3. sync digital media files to this device 4. Open device to view files 5. take no action

Comment: its probably option 4 and one more thing..you have a app called developer settings in that app you need to check the box labeled USB debugging

Answer (score 0):

First, You want to install usb driver for samsung. You can find here.

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117

Then, You want to install ADB driver using ADB installer.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979

This is Universal ADB driver Installer. You can use for all branded phones.